# Why does file.write() add an extra string at the end?

Tags: python, file, io

I was updating a text file with python (3.6), with open r+

```
with open(f+'.play', 'r+') as f2:
  play = f2.read()
  result = manipulate(play)
  print(result)
  f2.seek(0, 0)
  f2.write(result)
```

by doing this, I get an unexpected extra ending part

```
</soap:Envelope>ap:Envelope>
```

of course the extra part is after the first closing >

I fixed this by doing

```
with open(f+'.play', 'r+') as f2:
  play = f2.read()
  result = manipulate(play)
  print(result)
  f2.seek(0, 0)
  f2.truncate()
  f2.write(result)
```

in this case the write works as I expect.

Nevertheless I do not understand why I need to truncate, is the seek(0,0) not enough? 
because in my mind seek(0) + write should be overwrite the whole content in a proper way, what piece of knowledge am I missing here?

Comment: Please add your code sample. It is easier to understand and to avoid any unnecessary questions.

Answer (score 1):

If your old content has bigger size than one you are writing, the extra part will stay in the file. When you call `seek(0, 0)` you go to the beginning and start writing from there byte by byte, but the old data is not removed. When you call `truncate()` you remove old data, so it works as you want.